# ask cli init is generating a TypeError

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm using node version `v9.10.0`, and I'm following [this](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html) tutorial.
Because of `ask init`, I was able to initialize the profile(for the first time not for further usage of the same), and I'm getting this error, thereafter (when I try to overwrite my profile) ::

```
? Please create a new profile or overwrite the existing profile.
 [Nikhil Sanjay Wagh]       "default"
(node:3316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at inquirer.prompt.then (C:\Users\Nikhil Wagh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ask-cli\lib\init\init.js:87:55)
    at <anonymous>
(node:3316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3316) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

(Please don't mind the formatting, I just prefer this format to put the error.)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the error. **Either create a new profile or overwrite the existing profile.**

Based on your choice you can run one of the the below commands.

```
ask init -p default
```

or

```
ask init
```